# Connect Create SMS API with Voiceflow - Tips?

Tags: api, sms, voice

Has anyone ever used the create SMS API in order to send messages through voiceflow?
I'm creating a voice prototype that should trigger SMS but I can't get the API to respond properly.

My overall knowledge of APIs is pretty limited, anyone out there who wants to support a newbie?

The values I'm entering on voiceflow are:
Request URL: [https://api.twilio.com/2021-10-14/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json](https://api.twilio.com/2021-10-14/Accounts/%7BAccountSid%7D/Messages.json)
As an account SID I'm using my auth token, is that the right approach?
Params: To; From; Body